# word interop embed fonts when converting to pdf c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am using the following to save word to pdf:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application _wordApp;

_wordApp.ActiveDocument.EmbedTrueTypeFonts = true;
_wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(MergedDocumentFullOutputPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

I am able to save as pdf but few fonts are not embedding. I want to embed the system fonts too if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Word 2013-2016 does not support font embedding using Open Type Fonts (.otf) or other formats, it only fully supports it using **TrueType Fonts** (.ttf).

To fix the problem, all you have to do is follow this simple steps:

1. Convert the font to .ttf using a converter. I used this website
   [Online Font Converter](https://onlinefontconverter.com/).
2. Install the converted files. You will be
   prompted that the font is already install, choose "yes" to replace
   the old installation.
3. Enjoy :)

Comment: Same for Word 2010. Thank you very much for this hint. Solved my problem!

Comment: Same for Office 365 in year 2023.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify this option, which may embed some fonts that would not otherwise be embedded.

```
_wordApp.ActiveDocument.DoNotEmbedSystemFonts = false;
```